# Is read(n) compatible with mock_open?

Tags: python, python-mock

[**Update:** This is [a known bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue31855).]

Is there a way to use `read(some_number_of_bytes)` with `mock_open`?

`mock_open` works as expected when reading the entire file (`read()`) or when reading a single line (`readline()`), but I can't get it working when reading a number of bytes (`read(n)`)

These snippets (adapted from the [Mock documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open)) work (Python 2.7):

```
from mock import mock_open, patch

# works: consume entire "file"
with patch('__main__.open', mock_open(read_data='bibble')) as m:
    with open('foo') as h:
        result = h.read()

assert result == 'bibble'  # ok

# works: consume one line
with patch('__main__.open', mock_open(read_data='bibble\nbobble')) as m:
    with open('foo') as h:
        result = h.readline()

assert result == 'bibble\n'  # ok
```

But trying to read only a few bytes fails--`mock_open` returns the entire `read_data` instead:

```
# consume first 3 bytes of the "file"
with patch('__main__.open', mock_open(read_data='bibble')) as m:
    with open('foo') as h:
        result = h.read(3)

assert result == 'bib', 'result of read: {}'.format(result)  # fails
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/t.py", line 25, in <module>
    assert result == 'bib', 'result of read: {}'.format(result)
AssertionError: result of read: bibble
```

---

In case this is an XY problem, I'll note that the reason for this question is that I'm mocking a file that I pass into `pickle.load`, which in turn calls `read(1)`.

```
with open('/path/to/file.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    x = pickle.load(f)  # this requires f.read(1) to work
```

I'd prefer to mock the lowest level possible (`open` rather than `pickle.load`).

Comment: This looks like a bug (or at least a flaw) in `mock_open`. Consider [reporting it](https://bugs.python.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip - opened an issue. https://bugs.python.org/issue31855

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, this issue [has been fixed in Python 3.7](https://bugs.python.org/issue31855).